# How to check for time/date conflicts (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, time, conflict

We currently have a system, where we have a function that checks for date/time conflicts, that we manually populate all possible date/time conflicts as parameters to.

ie:

```
//session conflicts checker
function chkConflicts($sessions) {
    if (!is_array($sessions)) {
        $arrsessions = explode(',', $sessions);
    } else {
        $arrsessions = $sessions;
    }
    $conflictcount = 0;
    foreach ($arrsessions as $thissession) {
        if (($_POST[trim($thissession)] != '' && $_POST[trim($thissession)] != 0) || $_POST[trim($thissession) . '_faculty'] != '' && $_POST[trim($thissession) . '_faculty'] != 0) {
            $conflictcount++;
        }
    }
    if ($conflictcount > 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

used like so:

```
if (!chkConflicts('hours_5_p02_800, hours_5_p03_800, hours_5_p07_800, hours_5_p04_800')) {
            $errmsg .= 'There is a conflict at 8:00am in the selections. ';
        }
```

its very tedious, and time consuming to find these as well as manually populate the functions/params..

I need a new approach!  I'm hoping to just get a list of the conflicts back and highlight the (table) row on the page with a message about you have conflicts in the highlighted areas (less specific then giving an exact time..etc, and still gets the job done for the user)

All the user interaction is done by checkboxes, that have a name that reflects the column in the table:

ie:

```
hours_5_p02_800, hours_5_p03_800, hours_5_p07_800,     
hours_5_p04_800,hours_9_reg_session_300_845
```

(same names used in the chkConflicts function above)

I have (among others) two columns:  `sessiondate varchar(255)  & presentationtime varchar(255)` respectfully.

With the session date data looking like: 9/9/2015

And the presentation time data looking like: 8:45 AM - 9:05 AM  (not sure if this matters, but including it for the sake of full disclosure)

I dont have ALOT of control over the database, but I could probably get the times split into two columns (start/end) if that would be best?

before ANY chkConflict function is called.. the 'selections' of the user are recorded/saved to the table..  AND THEN the conflict check is called.

```
//record hours for each day
function recordHours() {
    $arrflds = explode(',', $_POST['fieldlist']);
    $sql = "UPDATE {$this->eventcode}_cme SET";
    foreach($arrflds as $key) {
        $sql .= " " . addslashes(trim($key)) . " = '" . addslashes($_POST[trim($key)]) . "',";
    }
    $sql .= " lastupdated = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "' WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION[$this->eventcode . '_id'] . "'";
    $this->debugout .= ($this->debug) ? 'Record hours: ' . $sql . '<br>' . $this->crlf : '';
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or exit('Error recording hours: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

*I'm updating things to PDO after I get the conflict stuff figured out. (thanks)

I dont mind this, because the chkConflict function (even though the choices have been saved) does NOT let the user move ahead until the error(s) message is taken care of (hence updating the table again when the conflicts are resolved)..

I'm thinking I'll need to no longer use the the chkConflict method and alter the recordHours function to not only update the table.. but because it has the 'fieldlist' array that was posted.. that I'll need to do the conflict checking there as well... or possibly call another function from withing recordHours and pass along the same fieldlist...

The column data is not really used for saving or (current) conflict checking of any sort...   the column NAME is.

My problem is I'm not sure how to go do the date/time conflict check?

re-cap:  fieldlist and column names are named like:

```
ie:  hours_5_p02_800, hours_5_p03_800, hours_5_p07_800,hours_5_p04_800,hours_9_reg_session_300_845
```

(and is a 24 hour format for the time)

ex: `hours_9_reg_session_300_845`

```
9 = date
reg =  event code
300 = session code
845 = session time(24-hour format)
```

Upon thinking more, its more like I need to do some sort of string parsing in PHP (on the fieldlist names) and do conversion/checking on that?

I need to take the string, break it down into its parts and do some sort of (concatenate/string building) comparison on it?

basically I get list of the fields being submitted that are formatted as above and match the table column names...

how can I pass this same fieldlist over to a new function (or whatever) to get any conflicts back?

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem have the chance to change things a little I would suggest you to create the 2 fields but as timestamps field type. One for the start and one for the end.

You can look at timestamps fields as a date/time like `2015-10-17 08:45:00` or, using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-10-17 08:45:00')`, as an integer like `1445064300` which is exactly the same date/time info.

In both cases you can do things like

```
SELECT :yourdatetime BETWEEN date_time_start AND date_time_end;
```

or

```
SELECT :yourunixlikedatetime
NOT BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time_start) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time_end);
```

for instance...

Comment: Thanks for the comment...

It seems (the more I look at it, and as explained above)  I would need to possibly do this on thr PHP sided of things..  using the fieldlist array instead of in/as a MySQL function..

I also do not think your example really goes with the current project.

There are anywhere from 1 - x checkboxes selected by the users.. these (fieldlist array) is then sent to be saved a table.

I need to check if ANY of the list are in conflict.  I am not selecting one.. they are selecting many.

Comment: Hmm.. you are probably correct, after more thinking the fieldlist-array names probably can NOT be used as is, since there is no ending time in there to be used for anything.


maybe adding in the END time to the fieldlist names would be helpful?
I'm trying to find a way to AVOID having to manually look at session times, and add them to a function to see if any of them were selected to report back a conflict..  its very ... I dont know 'manual'?  lol